# Using $.when and $.done in AJAX and trying to get result when it is done

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am calling AJAX calls and everytime I call an ajax call I pass it to a function to handle it. I do this because I am keeping a counter of AJAX requests at one time (mainly using that for development purposes). I am trying to retrieve the results of the AJAX call and put then manipulate that data.

Let me paste some code for better clarity.

```
function GET_allSystems() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: getSystemUrl(), // Unimportant, I call the url from a method
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json"
    });
}

// This will automatically increment and decrement the semaphore variable
// and execute functions when AJAX call is done.
function processAjaxCall(performAjaxCall, doFunctionWhenDone) {
    ajaxCall++;
    $.when(performAjaxCall).done(function (result) {
        ajaxCall--;
        doFunctionWhenDone(result);
    });
}

// I process the ajax to get all system information then put it in an object
processAjaxCall(GET_allSystems, function (result) {
    systemMap["systems"] = result;
});
```

Currently I am getting the function as a result, GET_allSystems() instead of the actual json of data I would normally get.

I want to pass the ajax calls through that function because it allows me to know if an AJAX call is currently in process and it just provides a level of abstraction I would like.

So clearly I am doing something wrong, but I would imagine that the $.done would execute when the ajax call is finished and pass the results back...but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke `performAjaxCall`:

```
function processAjaxCall(performAjaxCall, doFunctionWhenDone) {
    ajaxCall++;
    $.when(performAjaxCall()/* Call the function */).done(function (result) {
        ajaxCall--;
        doFunctionWhenDone(result);
    });
}
```

`performAjaxCall` returns an ajax promise object that is used by `$.when`.